# ImageView.setImageDrawable did not work in LANDSCAPE mode

Tags: java, android

I'm programming a socket client app.

App is very sample, Activty start a new socket thread to connect server. thread recive command from server and change ImageView by setImageDrawable.

There only one ImageView in layout. socket thread will use BufferedReader to get command from server, it command line is "start", socket thread will send message to main activity to execute setImageDrawable.

Here is my question:
Everything is okay in PORTRAIT mode. but did mot work in LANDSCAPE mode.

1. Everything is okay in PORTRAIT mode. picture changed in imageview.
2. When app work by LANDSCAPE mode. imageview.setImageDrawable in main activty will not work by message been send from socket thread, when and only when "new socket thread” -> "BufferedReader" -> "swith"
3. imageview.setImageDrawable has been executed and no error, it just don't work!

blow is layout:

```
    package com.example.whiletest;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.SocketTimeoutException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class WhileTest extends Activity {

    private ImageView ivTest;
    private TextView tvState;
    private Handler handler = null;
    private String strTemp; 

    private Message message=new Message();



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        /* set app to LANDSCAPE mode  */
        this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_while_test);
        tvState = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        ivTest = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        /* Change UI by main activity*/
        handler = new Handler() { 
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) { 
            switch (msg.what) { 
                case 110: 
                    ivTest.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.btn_camera_recording));
                    ivTest.postInvalidate();
                    System.out.println("OKAYAYHHAHS");
                break;
                case 112:
                    tvState.setText("收到指令  = " + strTemp);
                break;
            } 
            super.handleMessage(msg); 
            } 
            };



        new Thread(){
            @Override

            public void run()
            {
                Socket socketNet;
                  try{

                    socketNet = new Socket("192.168.2.104",3302);       //make connection
                    System.out.println("Connected!!!");

                    BufferedReader bff=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socketNet.getInputStream()));
                    PrintWriter os=new PrintWriter(socketNet.getOutputStream());

                    while ((strTemp = bff.readLine()) != null){  

                        //got command from server then send message to main activity
                        System.out.println("readLine = " + strTemp);
                        message.what=112;
                        handler.sendMessage(message);

                        if( strTemp.equals("start")){

                            message.what=110; 
                            handler.sendMessage(message);

                        }
                    };

                } catch (SocketTimeoutException aa) {
                    System.out.println("TimeOut");
                }catch (Exception e){   
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
         }.start();

    }

}
```

Below is layout

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.whiletest.WhileTest" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="138dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="163dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is server.java

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;



public class Server{

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        try{
            ServerSocket server=null;
            try{    
                server=new ServerSocket(3302);
            }catch(Exception e) {
                System.out.println("can not listen to:"+e);
            }

            Socket socket=null;
            try{
                socket=server.accept();
                System.out.println("accepted.");
            }catch(Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Error."+e);
            }

            String line="start";
            BufferedReader is=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            final PrintWriter os=new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());

            Timer timer=new Timer();
            timer.schedule(new TimerTask(){
                public void run() {
                    os.println("start");
                    os.flush();
                    //System.out.println("Command Sended" + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()));
                }
            } , 1000, 1000);

        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Error:"+e);
        }

    }
}
```

I have working on it for 3days. Please help me.

Comment: When u change your device orientation, activity is created again. OnCreate is fired again. Handle device orientation change

Comment: @Light, might you have found a solution? I'm also seeing this. Even though my onConfigurationChanged() listener is fired everytime the orientation changes, when it goes into landscape, imageview.setimagedrawable() stops working and won't work even when switching back to portrait . Very weird.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this line in the manifest file, under the Activity you are in :

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```